# How to add Instagram model 'like' animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram

I trying to develop an iphone app which shows image feeds. In the app there is functions for liking ang disliking. I need the effect similar to that Instagram like.

Like and Dislike have separate images..

I'm confused on how to do this. So I haven't done any coding.

Is there any sample code,library available?

Thanx..

Comment: got a vid or picture as I don't use Instagram so don't know what you're referring to and thus can't give you a solution

Comment: do you just want to change image of the button when clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your -(void)viewDidLoad

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneFingerTwoTaps = 
      [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerTwoTaps)] autorelease];

    // Set required taps and number of touches
    [oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    // Add the gesture to the view/UIImageView
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];
```

Instead of [self view] use your UIImageView.

In the next step you create the action for double tapping on the image

```
- (void)oneFingerTwoTaps
{
  // Action for Fade In the "Heart"
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourlikeimageoverlay.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


//Add the image view to your main view
//(This is optional if it was created with Interface Builder)
...


CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;

//within the animation we will adjust the "opacity"
//value of the layer
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
//animation lasts 0.4 seconds
theAnimation.duration=0.4;
//and it repeats forever
theAnimation.repeatCount= 1e100f;
//we want a reverse animation
theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
//justify the opacity as you like (1=fully visible, 0=unvisible)
theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1];

//Assign the animation to your UIImage layer and the
//animation will start immediately
[imageView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation
                 forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
}
```